# Django-allauth: myappdomain.com/accounts/login redirects to myappdomain.com

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm following the tutorial here: http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/page/3/

I'm at the part where we go to myappdomain.com/accounts/login to see the login page, but for me the website is just redirecting back to the index page at myappdomain.com. Does anybody know what the issue might be? Thanks.

Comment: Is your [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url) setting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the issue was that I was already logged in as admin.

Go to the admin area and make sure you logout, then you should be able to go to myappdomain.com/accounts/login page enter your details here and get redirected only after you login.